# SOAP Client in C# from existing php proofOfConcept

Tags: c#, php, soap, basic-authentication

I have a SOAP-API with WSDL (to be exactly many WSDLs) and Basic-Auth with a lot of methods - via this API I can controll a software, therefore I need to validate and process the answers to decide which one to use next.
I have a little example in php which is working:

```
$wsdl = 'https//.....wsdl';
$parameter = Array(
            'login' => "un", 
            'password' => "pw", 
            'soap_version' => ..., 
            'exceptions' => True, 
            'trace' => 0
        );
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl, $parameter);
$request_copy = array(
            'parameters' => array(
                    'some_id' => '123',
                    'some_value' => '...'
            ),
        );
$response_copy = $client->__soapCall("copy", $request_copy);
```

In C# I found in the last days a lot of approaches
1. Parsing the information manually and sending manual post requests
2. Adding Service Reference to the wsdl (in visual studio)

1. Isn't an option, because there are like 500 API-methods with a lot of different answer-types and so on
2. Idea sounds good, but I can't find a way to make it work

I have an empty console application with added service reference - the namespace (calling it "ExampleNamespace") includes all relevant classes (for one wsdl), but I couln't find a way to send the request.
I searched in all classes (API-methods are translated to classes in this ExampleNamespace if I'm getting it right) and could not find anything.

What I found is a class called like the added web reference (and no API method has that name) with an member ClientCredentials, which contains Username, so I have:

```
ExampleNamespace.FoundClass soap = new ExampleNamespace.FoundClass();
soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "un";
soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pw";
```

Also I found in some forum the hint, that the app.config has to contain something like the following  to work with basic auth

```
<security mode="Transport" >
   <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="">
      <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
   </transport>
</security>
```

In summary:
I can't find a (helpful) way to make a SOAP-requast in c#, I haven't found an example or anything really helpful. If anyone has a hint, an example, a solution or anything would be very helpful - there are a lot of threads on different forums, but nowhere is a good congregation of all necessary things

Thanks

Comment: What errors does the "Add service reference" approach give?

Comment: No, I just don't find a function to request anything

Comment: When you add a service reference you choose a namespace for it.  Check the classes in that namespace for a new generated service proxy. Visual studio should have done that for you.